# Change url location when click function fired in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am new to React and want to change location or my url.I have two react app on my local system. One is running in port 3000 & other is running on 3001.
I want that when i click on button then my url changes from `http://localhost:3000` to `http://localhost:3001`

When i am using react-router `history.push` it doesn't replace url, it appends url like: `http://localhost:3000/localhost:3001`

I also use `window.location = "localhost:3001/"` but in this case url is not changing.

my code is below:

```
 <Button type="button" color="primary" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>

handleSubmit = (event) =>{
    this.props.history.push('https://localhost:3001');
}
```

Comment: Url? That's a change in port :/

Comment: Try updating the `window.location` https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Comment: `window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3001'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
 window.location.assign("http://localhost:3001");
```

Comment: Welcome. You might want to accept the answer as the correct one by clicking on the tick beside it. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hard change location, you can use `window.location` object. However, if you want to keep within the app, you don’t need to do a browser location change. Most react apps utilize the history object to push new routes:

```
history.push(“/route”);
```

I suggest using a react routing library to handle these navigations, ex `react-router`. Then you can replace your link callbacks with `Link` components.